# Почему на сайтах не используется отступ для начала красной строки?

Tags: css, вёрстка, текст, отступы, работа-с-текстом

Почему даже на сайтах, основной контент которых основан на каких-то статьях, написания большого количества текста, не используется отступ на первом предложении при каждом новом абзаце?
Для этого есть своё css свойство, `text-indent`.
Грубо говоря, в школе всегда учили его ставить. А в интернете такого просто днем с огнем не сыщешь.
Почему такой отступ опускают всегда даже на новостных сайтах, где за форматированием смотрят (на нормальных сайтах), чтобы оно было идеальным?

Comment: Ну, это вопрос дизайна... На сайтах ведь нет длинных текстов, где красная строка помогает визуально отделять абзацы. Сегодня, если текст длиннее абзаца и они, абзацы, не разбавлены картинками, люди его не читают. "Многа букаф". Поэтому смысла в красной строке нет.

Comment: Наверное потому, что для выделения абзаца используется межстрочный интервал, который больше, чем интервал между строками внутри абзаца

Comment: Так исторически сложилось, что абзацы в интернет документах выделяются не красной строкой, а пространством между блоками текста. Именно так работает `<p>` и работал еще до появления CSS, теперь это уже привычка.